# android compiler error, no error in the file

Tags: android

[image: compiler error]

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.oneca.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar')}
```

this is the data in the build.gradle. No grammar error in the java file. what is wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You need to make a more expanded issue description

Answer (score 1):

Update your **minSdkVersion**.

> minSdkVersion 24

because  your lib **implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar')}**

not support below SdkVersion 24.